# Posting public key

Tags: security, personal-website

Should I put my public PGP key on my website so that people can securely contact me? I have seen personal sites where their public key is at the bottom of the page, such as [this site](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/) by the computer scientist Peter Gutmann.

1. How should I include the key in my page?
2. Is there a standardized way to include the key?

Many sites include them at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it to your web page as in the link you cited, or a slightly more *elegant* way might be to upload it to a public PGP Key Server, such as [this](https://keyserver.pgp.com/vkd/GetWelcomeScreen.event) or [this](http://pgp.mit.edu/) one, and then add the link to the page for your key on your web page.

If you also use the link within your emails and files, then you'll be able to update your public key in just one place.

You could also use a [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) to prevent bots from indexing your key, and/or use JavaScript to copy it for the user (between the BEGIN and END blocks).

Comment: Thanks, This key server https://keyserver.pgp.com/vkd/GetWelcomeScreen.event sounds best suited for my needs.

Comment: No problem. Other than the above, there's really no "standard" way to add it to your page, though you should include the BEGIN and END blocks if you decide to just print it there.

Comment: BTW, the MIT Key Server is pretty popular among academics too, as indicated in CS department help docs like [here](http://accc.uic.edu/answer/how-do-i-share-pgp-keys-others).

Comment: Looks like you added a link to your bio for your public key at the MIT Key Server - interesting idea, maybe you'll start a trend :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add it to your site, I would suggest using a separate page to hold it. Put a link to that page at the bottom of every page.

For the key itself, it should be in a textarea element. This allows the exact key to be copy-pasted more easily without extra spaces or any formatting. You can use the `readonly` attribute to prevent accidental modification of the field.